# Error while storing sin(2) in an array like [ "sin", "(", "2", ")" ]. How to do it?

Tags: arrays, c, string, parsing

I want to store a every element of a string `sin(2)` in an array like `[ "sin", "(", "2", ")" ]`.

To go through every character I am using a `while` loop.

Storing words like I am using a char array named `box` which will keep storing a letter until `sin` gets formed. Whether letters inserted form `sin` or not will be checked in first `if` section of `while` loop.

Then if `sin` is detected, it will be inserted in `tokens[]` as a string.

Then next comes the character `(`. It will be inserted in tokens[]. Same goes for `2`, `)`.

Then after the `while` loop gets fully executed it's not giving me output as  `tokens[0]` as `sin`.

The output is `'' is in the tokens`.

Why is this happening?
Pls Help.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct stores {
    char *tokens[10];
    char *box;
} stores_t;

int main() {
    stores_t storer;
    storer.box = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char *supp[1] = { "sin" };
    char *exp = "sin(2)";

    int i = 0;
    while (exp[i] != '\0') {
        if (isalpha(exp[i])) {
            storer.box[i] = exp[i];
            if (strcmp(storer.box, supp[0]) == 0) {
                storer.tokens[i] = strdup(storer.box);
                i++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        } else
        if (exp[i] == '(') {
            storer.tokens[i] = (exp[i]);
            i++;
        } else
        if (exp[i] == ')') {
            storer.tokens[i] = exp[i];
            i++;
        } else
        if (isdigit(exp[i]) == 0) {
            storer.tokens[i] = exp[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("'%s' is in the tokens\n", storer.tokens[0]);
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. `storer.tokens[i] = exp[i];` is nonsense., since `exp[i]` is `char`, and `storer.tokens[i]` holds `char*`. This same mistake happens in three places (at least).

Comment: Sumeet, <I want to store a every element of a string `sin(2)` in an array like `[  "sin",  "(",  "2",  ")"  ]`.> is unclear.  The _elements_ of a _string_ are `char`, not `char *`.  I may see what you want, but the terms need improvement to provide clarity.  More like: <I want to tokenize the string ...>

Comment: It sounds like you wish to use `strok` and use spaces as well as `'('` and `')'` for separators.